# Is there other basis possible for DFT?

Tags: dft, frequency

As I understand, the DFT of a signal $x$ is a representation of this signal in the basis

$$ \{ e^{j2\pi kn/N} \}_{k = 0, 1, \dots, N-1}$$

Is it possible to form a base of such discrete complex exponentials but with different frequencies ? ($\{ e^{j2\pi f_i n} \}$)

Why did we choose these $\frac{k}{N}$ frequencies ?

In fact, my question is more about why we evaluate the DFT at these specific frequencies and not others.

Comment: The DFT basis consists of all possible complex exponentials which have period N.

Comment: IIRC the frequencies you choose will not be orthogonal.

Answer (score 8):

$k/N$ with $N$ bases is the only basis which is all of:

1. **Orthogonal & invertible**. Means we don't lose any information. Invertibility can be seen to follow from the DFT being a square (N x N) matrix of rank N (orthogonal = all columns independent), so we can solve $Ax = y$ with $x = A^{-1}y$.
2. **$N$-periodic**. Every basis will repeat after $N$ uniform samples. This makes the DFT a uniform & $N$-periodic [sampling of one period of DTFT](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#/Sampling_the_DTFT) which yields many useful properties, and enables circular convolution.
3. **Minimal**. Maps out the greatest continuous-time bandwidth per unit sample, meaning it's max information-dense. This follows the [sampling theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), which demands a minimum of $N$ samples to capture a bandwidth up to (but not including) $N/2$ (in physical terms, sampling at rate of $f_s$ to capture $f_s/2$). Other bases will take $N$ or more samples (if succeeding at all, see example).

$2k/N$ with $N$ bases is orthogonal and $N$-periodic, but not minimal, nor invertible. In fact it's not invertible for any number of bases, ironically due to periodicity. $Gk/N$, where $G$ is non-integer, is none of those things with $N$ bases. I'll also informally add,

4. **Exact**. Follows from 1. Non-orthogonality implies a base has non-zero correlation with other bases, meaning e.g. frequency of 1.5 means "1.5, and a bit of 2.5, and a bit of 0.5, and ...". Though, the part in quotes is a bit tricky depending on interpretation, since it happens no matter what for a realistic input (e.g. spectral leakage).

Comment: It would be great if you could include the proof, or cite a proof, that there is no other basis that satisfies all the four properties.

Comment: @AlexTP Fair, wouldn't know from top of my head though. Think it could be shown by considering every possible $N$-base cisoid basis that's orthogonal and $N$-periodic, then checking which also meets sampling theorem criteria, so a sort of system of equations.