# Choice of relationship between n_fft and window_length in STFT

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, stft, time-frequency, statistics

Not a veteran in Signal Processing, it would be extremely appreciated to help me understand the idea/heuristic behinde the idea in STFT that

$$\text{nfft} \ge \text{window length}$$

At least from a statistical perspective, I believe it's an overfit to the estimate of each coefficient of each frame of STFT given the following reason:

For $X_1,X_2,X_n\sim D\in [-1, 1]$, we can apply an basis approach to estimate its probability density function: $$p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{
\infty}\theta_i \phi_i(x)$$ where $\phi_i(x)$ is an orthogonal function, which satisfies:
\begin{cases}
\int_{-1}^{1}\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x) dx=0 & i\neq j\\ \int_{-1}^{1}\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)dx=1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

At the essence of STFT (one frame), each coefficient represents an estimation of coefficient ($\hat{\theta}_i$) of the first $\text{nfft}$ basis functions, given the $\text{window length}$ number of audio sample.

Let $N = \text{window length}$ and $\hat{p}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\text{nfft}}\hat{\theta}_i\phi_i(x)$ where each $\hat{\theta}_i$ is estimated by
$$\hat{\theta}_j = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}\phi_j(X_I)$$
It can be shown that this is an unbiased estimator of $\theta_j$ and has a nice property: if choosing $\text{nfft}=C_0(N)^{1/5}$ then the convergence of the mean square error between $p(x)$ and $\hat{p}(x)$ is optimal $O(N^{-4/5})$

And surely, when

$$\text{nfft} \ge \text{window length}$$

it will be either $C_0$ is quite large (so that $\text{nfft}=\text{window length}$ actually makes sense) or we may not follow the best relationship between $\text{nfft}$ and $\text{window length}$ ($\text{nfft}=C_0(\text{window length})^{1/5}$) for the optimal estimation of $p(x)$

Comment: Tip, `$\text{nfft}$`, more [here](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076). Also [revelant](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84746/50076). Note `nfft >= win_len` isn't a preference but necessity.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Nice catch for the formatting refinement, great thanks :) However, I am still having difficulties addressing the `revelant` post directly to this question: any further clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`nfft >= win_length` is a forced implementation detail of the columnwise implementation of STFT: each column of STFT is just `x` multiplied by a certain shifting of `window`, followed by `fft`, and of course we can't have `len(fft(x * window)) < len(window)`. Columnwise however isn't the only implem.

I don't know where your equations come from, but they're wrong: there is no relationship between `win_length` and quality of estimation. There *is* a relationship with `window`, but that's only completely determined by `win_length` for a few common windows: what matters is the [width and Heisenberg resolutions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/80920/50076).

Lastly, note that STFT is not an orthogonal transform, and the "windowed Fourier transform" is but one of its interpretations. Truer to time-frequency analysis, STFT is convolution with windowed complex sinusoids, i.e. bandpass filters, where `hop_length` is stride. It's the [top visual here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/78513/50076), except widths are fixed in time and frequency, and frequencies are linearly spaced.